# Hibernate Envers: Rename REVINFO table

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I have two questions about REVINFO table.

1. Can I change the REVINFO Table to something like "RVSN_INFO"?
2. If I'm auditing 9 tables. Should every table have a REVINFO table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can create an entity and annotate it with `@RevisionEntity`. If you don't have it, the default named table `REVINFO` is created. Check out [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/#revisionlog) for more info.
2. No, a single table holds information for all revisions.

Comment: It would have been so perfect  having a revinfo table for each audited entity